# Unity Buttons: non-rectangular shape

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, assets, shapes

Please see the image attached to understand me. You can see Button One and Button two. But unfortunately buttons are always rectangular but i want it to be parallelogram shape.

[image: Image attached]

Please help me guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was already done before and is still working

Checkout [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/none-rectangle-shaped-button.263684).

The setup:

**Adjust your shape texture and make it**

- As usual a Sprite (2D and UI)
- MeshType = Full Rect
- Read/Write Enabled = true

[image]

**Put your buttons under a [`Mask`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Mask.html)** object so you have a hierarchy like

```
Canvas
|---MaskObject1 (with trapez texture)
|   |---Button1
|
|---MaskObject2
    |---Button2
```

**On your `Mask` have an additional component `RaycastMask`**.

The script looks like this

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
 
[RequireComponent(typeof(RectTransform))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Image))]
public class RaycastMask : MonoBehaviour, ICanvasRaycastFilter
{
    private Image _image;
    private Sprite _sprite;
 
    void Start ()
    {
        _image = GetComponent<Image>();
    }
 
    public bool IsRaycastLocationValid(Vector2 sp, Camera eventCamera)
    {
        _sprite = _image.sprite;
 
        var rectTransform = (RectTransform)transform;
        Vector2 localPositionPivotRelative;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle((RectTransform) transform, sp, eventCamera, out localPositionPivotRelative);
 
        // convert to bottom-left origin coordinates
        var localPosition = new Vector2(localPositionPivotRelative.x + rectTransform.pivot.x*rectTransform.rect.width,
            localPositionPivotRelative.y + rectTransform.pivot.y*rectTransform.rect.height);
     
        var spriteRect = _sprite.textureRect;
        var maskRect = rectTransform.rect;
 
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        // convert to texture space
        switch (_image.type)
        {
         
            case Image.Type.Sliced:
            {
                var border = _sprite.border;
                // x slicing
                if (localPosition.x < border.x)
                {
                    x = Mathf.FloorToInt(spriteRect.x + localPosition.x);
                }
                else if (localPosition.x > maskRect.width - border.z)
                {
                    x = Mathf.FloorToInt(spriteRect.x + spriteRect.width - (maskRect.width - localPosition.x));
                }
                else
                {
                    x = Mathf.FloorToInt(spriteRect.x + border.x +
                                         ((localPosition.x - border.x)/
                                         (maskRect.width - border.x - border.z)) *
                                         (spriteRect.width - border.x - border.z));
                }
                // y slicing
                if (localPosition.y < border.y)
                {
                    y = Mathf.FloorToInt(spriteRect.y + localPosition.y);
                }
                else if (localPosition.y > maskRect.height - border.w)
                {
                    y = Mathf.FloorToInt(spriteRect.y + spriteRect.height - (maskRect.height - localPosition.y));
                }
                else
                {
                    y = Mathf.FloorToInt(spriteRect.y + border.y +
                                         ((localPosition.y - border.y) /
                                         (maskRect.height - border.y - border.w)) *
                                         (spriteRect.height - border.y - border.w));
                }
            }
                break;
            case Image.Type.Simple:
            default:
                {
                    // conversion to uniform UV space
                    x = Mathf.FloorToInt(spriteRect.x + spriteRect.width * localPosition.x / maskRect.width);
                    y = Mathf.FloorToInt(spriteRect.y + spriteRect.height * localPosition.y / maskRect.height);
                }
                break;
        }
 
        // destroy component if texture import settings are wrong
        try
        {
            return _sprite.texture.GetPixel(x,y).a > 0;
        }
        catch (UnityException e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Mask texture not readable, set your sprite to Texture Type 'Advanced' and check 'Read/Write Enabled'");
            Destroy(this);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The result looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can have the same result with 1 line of code adding a new script on your Button:

1. within this script, on `Start()` just write:

   ```
   GetComponent<Image>().alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold = 0.1f;
   ```
2. But you need to change the settings of your image as mentioned above:

   - Sprite (2D and UI)
   - MeshType = Full Rect
   - Read/Write Enabled = true
3. Link to the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QxN7hQXkO8

Answer (score -1):

In your Button source Image, in your Button component, you can use the **UISprite** default button sprite of Unity for the button.

If you go to your Canvas Game Object | **Canvas Scaler Component / Reference Pixels Per Unit** and increase the value, the button will be more rounded, if you decrease the value the button will be more rectangular.

Comment: This will not answer OP's question how to get differently shaped buttons regarding to not how they are rendered but rather how they are interacting though ...